# How do I create a timestamp in an embed with pycord?

Tags: discord, bots, pycord

I would like my sent msg log which is an embedded msg to have a timestamp, so it would have a footing like bot_name • Today at 10:48 PM

Here is my current code,

````
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author.bot: return
    else:
        log_msg = bot.get_channel(1023451687857442828)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Sent Message",
            description = f"""This message was sent by{ctx.author.mention}, in {ctx.channel}\n**Message:** "{ctx.content}" """,
            color = discord.Colour.green(),
        )
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author)
        embed.set_footer(text="bot_name")
        await log_msg.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
(remaining of your code)
now = datetime.now() # Gets your current time as a datetime object
embed.set_footer(text=f'bot_name • Today at {now.strftime("%H:%M")}') # Set your embed footer with the formatted time
await log_msg.send(embed=embed) # Sends your footer (already present in your original code)
```

If you don't have it imported already, you'll have to `import datetime from datetime`, or `import datetime` and do `datetime.datetime.now()` instead of just `datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctx.message.created_at` to add a timestamp. That would look like this in the context of your code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author.bot: return
    else:
        log_msg = bot.get_channel(1023451687857442828)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Sent Message",
            description = f"""This message was sent by{ctx.author.mention}, in {ctx.channel}\n**Message:** "{ctx.content}" """,
            color = discord.Colour.green(),
            # message created at code below 
            timestamp = ctx.message.created_at 
        )
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author)
        embed.set_footer(text="bot_name")
        await log_msg.send(embed=embed)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think he wants it to include the timestamp of the original message in the embed's footer, but rather when the embed was sent by the bot.